# imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, png

when i try to out put image from url. 
But show the error like this : "The image "http://www.somesite.com/?data=JF123456" cannot be displayed because it contains error.

this my code :

```
$img = "1.png";//$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename);   
    //    Output handler
    function output_handler($img) {
        echo $img;
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($img));
        return $img;
    }

//  Image output
    ob_start("output_handler");
    imagepng($img,NULL,9);
    $image_data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_flush()
```

on my process : when program on computer(c#) enter url post value data = "JF123456" php file will generate qrcode, i get out put image png, to show image on Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)! You have to first obtain an image resource, returned by one of the image creation functions, such as [`imagecreatefrompng()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php):

```
$file = $PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename);
$img  = imagecreatefrompng($file);

// ...

ob_start("output_handler");
imagepng($img,NULL,9);
$image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Not working, show same error.

Comment: I try to close header to check, php page return "‰PNG  IHDR¤¤#{PLTEÿÿÿUÂÓ~rIDATHÇÕ–AvÃ@C¹÷¿%7P$w ›ÌkûO_04Žøµ ¢PÉŸä…n/(«*•Ú)“ÚWŒDÎíE<ùÜÑT&Üê#ª ÃËší¨žýµ^5ÞQ­«™ð»v”ßižV&¹n(«(Qôø¾ï€{ZÝ\×Ê+M_²W´×IPÊÍ&Ñ pO1÷4§€m%±N¨½°Ù£Ù–*\*(]C½WÝ"îBOÎ UÓA14/üŸ˜^_S‰Âšªd=¡ÔE¢/n(õ¦(G 7T^Üµ4uötÃg‰'æ¶´ÍºãˆêØ×ÚH³žjn©õ !µ7ãÑì€¦ZÏ7Úš¢ÉîéržQwJô?÷ÜÓ6|'£AœCdOûôŸD4,¯w‚ -·wÅ#Ú®”z8¤*!IÚ8âŒÊí¡>Ÿê†Æ8[;F¾ÞÁWÄ]'Eà†þÖú²>>Ë·\Q~IEND®B`‚" and 1 notice "Notice: Undefined index: data in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\qrcode\index.php on line 16"

Comment: You didn't read the manual. It shows *exactly* how to do this. Hint, look at the part that says `header('Content-Type: image/png');`.

Comment: I read manual already and i put  header('Content-Type: image/png'); already but the show message "The image "http://www.somesite.com/?data=JF123456" it same 

thank you for advice.